If $A_{3\times 3}$ is a matrix whose row sums are 1, and $\det(A)\neq 0$.Also, $B=I+A^{-1}+A^{-2}+A^{-3}$, then row sums of matrix B is?
This question appeared in an entrance test. I know there is an approach of solving it via, the use of eigenvalues, ($Av=v$), I wanted to solve it using characteristic polynomial, or some clever observation, I tried to let the $A$ matrix as $I$, I got the correct answer which is 4. But the answer seems a bit contrived.

Let $e$ be the vector of ones. You are given that $Ae=e$ and since $A$ is invertible, $A^{-1} e = e$, repeating shows that $A^k e = e$. Hence $Be = 4e$ and hence the row sums are all $4$.
